# How can I determine a maximum run length for CANbus?

Tags: can, signal-integrity, distance

I'm using CANbus to communicate between two circuit boards. 120 ohm termination resistors on either end. Transceivers are [MCP2561](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005167C.pdf) and [ISO1050](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005167C.pdf). Bit rate is in the hundreds of kilobits/second. Medium is four-conductor 22AWG twisted cable, with the other two conductors carrying 9V and signal/power common. I'm not concerned about voltage drop on the power lines, only about signal integrity.

Is there a means by which one might go about estimating the maximum run length of a configuration like this? I don't need an answer down to inches; an order-of-magnitude answer is close enough for my purposes. But I haven't any idea where to start.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CANbus but I have a question that may or may not help: Can you measure slew rate at a couple of shorter cable lengths and mathematically determine at what point it would be unusable?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CAN bus. Is the system in a 'noisy' environment, like a car, or a 'quiet' environment? If it is a vehicle, there appears to be a Specification for CAN bus [Physical Layer, 250 Kbps, Un-Shielded Twisted Pair (UTP)](http://standards.sae.org/j1939/15_201405/). However it's $70, and there are a lot of [SAE J1939](http://store.sae.org/j1939/contents/) standards; I assume each one is $70. I imagine it will give robust guidance, but might not be what you want.

Comment: @gbulmer J1939 is a Protocol based on CAN... It expects that it's Physical Layer i.e. CAN should work properly. It doesn't specify any guidelines or something. I have worked J1939 and never came across such things! OP is interested in Physical layer so J1939 documents may not be helpful!

Comment: @Swanand - so are you saying that you have access to the document [Physical Layer, 250 Kbps, Un-Shielded Twisted Pair (UTP)](http://standards.sae.org/j1939/15_201405/), and it does not describe the physical layer for UTP? I don't know either way, because I am not paying $70 to find out :-)

Comment: @gbulmer Yup... It doesn't go in detail... Just basic info that CAN would run 40m at 250Kbps etc, which would not be helpful for OP!

Answer (score 7):

I mainly depends on your required bit rate.  CAN works by the transmitter node checking that its bits are correctly on the bus.  There are two reasons in the protocol that this intentionally doesn't happen:

- If another transmitter is attempting to transmit, it overwrites some of the bits, and the lower priority message is held up.
- Receiver nodes can flag errors by overwriting bits.

Therefore, the total delay in the bus (including the delay through the PHY and controller at both ends, wiring delay and any opto-isolators) needs to be significantly less than the bit time.  Often the sampling point of the receivers (including the one in the node which is currently transmitting) is set up to be about 70% of the bit time, so you want your delay to be shorter than that.

For example (and this is a quick hack calculation with approximations in), a 500kbit/s bus has a bit time of 2us.

70% of that is 1.4us.

Assuming 100ns each way through the PHY and controllers, you lose 400ns there, so you have 1us for signal propagation in the wire.

The signal has to go out and back, so we have to halve that, giving 500ns.

Rule of thumb for coax propagation is 6 inches in 1ns (ugh, non-SI units, let's say ~6ns/m!).  (As Olin rightly points out, twisted pair will likely be somewhat faster). That would give a bus length of about 85m.

[CiA has some recommendations which seem less conservative than that, although were calculated for a later sampling point (87.5% IIRC)](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=158):

```
Bit rate    Bus length       
1 Mbit/s    25 m         
800 kbit/s  50 m         
500 kbit/s  100 m   
250 kbit/s  250 m    
125 kbit/s  500 m        
50 kbit/s   1000 m   
20 kbit/s   2500 m  
10 kbit/s   5000 m
```

Comment: This is the right idea, +1.  However, signal propagation on a transmission line will slower than in free space.  Light in vacuum propagates at 11.8 inches/ns, but slower on a transmission line.  The exact amount slower can be determined from the impedance, with lower impedance being slower.  Usually you conservatively figure 1/2 the speed of light in vacuum for a low impedance transmission line like 50 Ohm coax.  Speed will be faster on 120 Ohm twisted pair, but you still need to derate from the 11.8 inches/ns or 300 Mm/s vacuum propagation speed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - good catch - I know that tprop is slower in wire than freespace. Serves me right for pulling rules of thumb out of my memory and not checking them!  1ns==6inches is the rule of thumb I meant.  I'll update the answer!